# 2 to the power 2 n times incorrect

Tags: c++, recursion

Please tell me what is wrong, the output is wrong, shows 4 to me
F​1​ = 2, F​n​ = (F​n-1​)​
2​ , n ≥ 2
i. What is the complexity of the algorithm that computes ​F​n
using the recursive
definition given above.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    double calcFn(double,int);
    int main()
    {
    
    
        cout << calcFn(2, 4);
        cout << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    
    double calcFn(double F1, int N)
    {   
        cout << endl;
        double Fn = F1 * F1;
        while (N > 0)
        {   
            N--;
            calcFn(Fn, N);
        }
        return Fn;
        
    }

// CODE DOESNT SHOW the RIGHT oUTPUT
```

Comment: The loop does nothing since you're not using the return value from `calcFn`.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What should be the expected answer for calcFn(2, 4) ? Is it 16 ?

Comment: please see this (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a9Edb9) and compare your code.

Comment: Learn how to do recursion right. Or maybe even simulate on paper with a pen. That's an old method, but it works very well to find programing errors.

Comment: 2^2, 2^4, 2^8, 2^16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You have recurrency, so you should not use the loop. Secondly, You do not assign return value. The corrected snippet:

```
if (N > 0)
{   
  N--;
  Fn = calcFn(Fn, N);
}
```

Still, I'm not sure about the result, but You can further correct it.